# Can I ask a question for a tablet recommendation for doing mathematics?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

With all the technology available, I've been thinking of getting a tablet for doing all my mathematical calculations, taking notes in class. Obviously there is a bunch of options of tablets in the market, and so, it would be nice to hear what people are using. I tried google and I found some threads, even stackexchange threads. But all of these are kind of old (so much happens in 1 year in the technology). So math.stackexchange contains a lot of people who might be able to come up with some good answers/recommendations. But on the other hand, it is not (formally) a mathematical question. Would it be acceptable to ask such question? (I believe no), and if not. What is the best way to reach the crowd from math.stackexchange, from another forum?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about

Comment: You mentioned that you find some questions, but I will still add this link for benefit of others: [Tablet for reading textbooks and writing math by hand?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/193072) It is 5 years old, at that time questions of this type were better received. (Now it is closed as off-topic. The site has evolved.)

Comment: Perhaps you should post to a math related newsgroup like `sci.math` or on one of the discussion-style math forums (not Math.SE).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But all of these are kind of old (so much happens in 1 year in the technology)

That in itself is a reason for this type of question not being a good fit for the StackExchange model. This kind of question, where answers have short validity but the community of a StackExchange site would be a good group to ask, should be asked instead in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=math.stackexchange.com).